# Contact form 7: dynamic pre-selection text blocks

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have created a contact form with the contact form 7 plugin for wordpress.

Now I want to create 3 pre-selection text blocks, so that a user can choose for example between „Hello...“ „I looking for..“ „I have a question“. And this text block should be give over in the textarea field.

The purpose of this is, that a user do not need to write so many text. :-)

**IMPORTANT:**

I do not mean a select field... I want to have 3 or more values for the textarea message field. So that a user can choose „Hello, I am looking for...“ and this value is given over to the textarea and the user need only to complete the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Your field will look like this.

```
[select* menu-140 "Hello..." "I looking for.." "I have a question"]
```

[image]

Select a field drop-down type and select options according to your need.
required or not etc.. see the image will get understanding.
all Options in filed every new option in new line.
copy and paste the short-code and enjoy :)

Comment: I do not mean a select field... I want to have 3 or more values for the textarea message field. So that a user can choose „Hello, I am looking for...“ and this value is given over to the textarea and the user need only to complete the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
[text* your-name class:required "John Smith"]
```

your-name: Its your fields name
"John Smith" is the default value.

In this way you add a default value to a field.

Comment: And how can I add 3 or more values to a field?

Comment: Then you need to create multiple selectbox

Comment: I do not mean a select field... I want to have 3 or more values for the textarea message field. So that a user can choose „Hello, I am looking for...“ and this value is given over to the textarea and the user need only to complete the sentence.

Comment: do you have any demo link. So i better understand